# Clicar na imagem para ampliar

Tags: novo-recurso, layout, imagem

Não é o caso da maioria das vezes, mas às vezes os usuários colocam imagens muito grandes que acabam ficando muito pequenas e difíceis de ver.

Como exemplo, veja esta pergunta: [Mudança de Abas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22445/7261)

O único jeito de ver a imagem em tamanho maior é clicar com o botão direito e clicar em "Abrir em nova aba/guia":

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que no caso da pergunta citada aponta para cá: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1.png

Porém seria mais conveniente se pudéssemos apenas clicar na imagem para vê-la ampliada, como é comum em diversos sites internet afora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não acho necessário, pois acredito que na maioria dos sites essa não é uma funcionalidade automatizada, as imagens são `<img src="pequena">` e se quisermos linkar para a versão original colocamos uma âncora: `<a href="grande"><img src="pequena"></a>`.

Em markdown, o que se faz é encapsular a imagem como um link para ela mesma:

```
[![descrição da imagem para o google e pessoas cegas ou com visão reduzida][1]][1]
<sup>*clique para ampliar*</sup>

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1.png "tooltip: clique para ampliar"
```

[image: descrição da imagem]
<sup>*clique para ampliar*</sup>

O `<sup>` é opcional, mas o tooltip é legal colocar.

---

Bonus: acrescentar um `m` (medium) ou um `s` (small) ao nome do arquivo vai mostrar versões reduzidas das imagens:

```
[![descrição da imagem][2]][1]
[![descrição da imagem][3]][1]

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1.png "tooltip: clique para ampliar"
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1m.png 
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1s.png
```

[image: descrição da imagem]

[image: descrição da imagem]

<sub>**Sim**, [a qualidade das reduções é ruim mesmo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199889/imgur-medium-images-with-too-much-compression)...</sub>

---

Testando HTML com target:

```
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1.png">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1s.png">no target
</a>

<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1.png" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1s.png">target blank não funciona, o link é removido
</a>
```

[[image]no target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m46c1.png)

[image]target blank não funciona, o link é removido

Comment: Tem como forçar a imagem a abrir em uma nova aba?

Comment: Não tem jeito, confira o update...